# WP Rest Api- Update callback (POST request) to existing database table through the rest api

Tags: rest-api

I have registed a new rest route to existing database table called wpso_messages. I was able to create a get_callback function that fetches all the data from the database.

I want to add a POST request functionality, that allows me to introduce new data rows to the wpso_messages table through the rest api. Any advise how to accomplish that?

below is my code for registering the rest route and get_callback:

```
<?php



function get_wp_query() {
    global $wpdb;
    $rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wpso_messages");
    foreach( $rows as $index => $row ) {
    
           $user_from_id = $rows[$index]->user_from; 
           $user_to_id = $rows[$index]->user_to; 
           $rows[$index]->username_from = get_user_by('id', $user_from_id)->display_name;
           $rows[$index]->username_to = get_user_by('id', $user_to_id)->display_name;
    }
    return $rows;
};
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', 'messages', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_wp_query'
        ) );
    } );
```

For the POST request, below is an example of an input json to create new entry in the wpso_messages table:

```
{"user_from": "82", "user_to": "1", "message": "Iam interested to bid", "listing_id": "22775"}
```

Final Solution based on Sally C.J answer:
Note that it includes few checks such as that user ids are valid and that the key values in the json body are in the SQL database columns.

```
#GET request function

function get_wp_query() {
    global $wpdb;
    $rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wpso_messages");
    foreach( $rows as $index => $row ) {
    
           $user_from_id = $rows[$index]->user_from; 
           $user_to_id = $rows[$index]->user_to; 
           $rows[$index]->username_from = get_user_by('id', $user_from_id)->display_name;
           $rows[$index]->username_to = get_user_by('id', $user_to_id)->display_name;
           $rows[$index]->author= array('Welcome'=>'Home');
    }
    return $rows;
};

#POST request arguments validation

function my_create_item_args() {
    return array(
        'user_from' => array(
            'required'          => true,
            'validate_callback' => function ( $param ) {
                return is_numeric( $param );
            },
        ),
        'user_to' => array(
            'required'          => true,
            'validate_callback' => function ( $param ) {
                return is_numeric( $param );
            },
        ),
        'message'   => array(
            'required'          => true,
            'sanitize_callback' => function ( $param ) {
                // this allows basic HTML tags like <strong> and <em>
                #return wp_filter_kses( $param );

                // this allows line breaks, but strips all HTML tags
                return sanitize_textarea_field( $param );
            },
        ),
        'listing_id' => array(
            'required'          => true,
            'validate_callback' => function ( $param ) {
                return is_numeric( $param );
            },
        ),
        ''
        // ... other args.
    );
}

#Post request function
function post_function( WP_REST_Request $request ) {



    #getting json body
    $body = $request->get_json_params();
    
    #checking if there is an invalid entry otherwise it wont be processed (example unseen)
    $valid_entries=["user_from","message","user_to","listing_id","seen"];
    foreach( $body as $keysx1=>$valuesx1 ) {
        if (in_array($keysx1, $valid_entries, true)) {
        
        } else {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid entry', __($keysx1 . ' is an invalid entry'), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
        }
    }
    
    #######Checking users
    $users = get_users();
    foreach( $users as $user ) {
        // get user names from the object and add them to the array
        $useridlist[] = $user->id;
    }
    $userfromx1=$body['user_from'];
    $usertox1=$body['user_to'];
    #Checking sender and reciever are not same
    if ($userfromx1!=$usertox1) {
        
        } else {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid message', __('Sender and reciever cant be same'), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
        }
    #Checking userto and userfrom are in users list
    if (in_array($userfromx1, $useridlist, true)) {
        
        } else {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid user id', __('user id specified in user_from is invalid'), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
        }
    
    if (in_array($usertox1, $useridlist, true)) {
        
        } else {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid user id', __('user id specified in user_to is invalid'), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
        }
    
    global $wpdb;
    $body["created_at"] = current_time('mysql');
    $wpdb->insert('wpso_messages', $body);  
    return $body;

}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'my-plugin/v1', 'messages', array(array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_wp_query'
        ),
        array(
        'methods'  => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'post_function',
        'args'                => my_create_item_args(),
        'permission_callback' => function () {
        // This is just an example of checking the user's permissions..
        return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
    },)));
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to add a POST request functionality, that allows me to
> introduce new data rows to the wpso_messages table through the rest
> api. Any advise how to accomplish that?

Yes, and note that I wrote this based on the official [REST API handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) and the core endpoints.

So from the ["Routes and Endpoints → Routes vs Endpoints" section](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#routes-vs-endpoints) — note the part I highlighted:

> A route is the “name” you use to access endpoints, used in the URL.
> **A route can have multiple endpoints associated with it**, and which is used depends on the HTTP verb.

Where "HTTP verb" here is essentially a HTTP request method like GET or POST.

So for example, the core [`/wp/v2/posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/) route has 2 endpoints — one with a GET method (for retrieving posts) and the other with a POST method (for creating a post).

Therefore, you could follow the same approach, i.e. add an endpoint to your "messages" route, possibly with the POST method, like so:

```php
// I intentionally used my-plugin as the vendor name, and not "wp". See the
// "Additional Notes" at the bottom in my answer.
register_rest_route( 'my-plugin/v2', 'messages', array(
    // Endpoint 1 - list items.
    array(
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_wp_query',
        // ... other args.
    ),

    // Endpoint 2 - create items.
    array(
        'methods'  => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'my_create_item',
        // ... other args.
    )
) );

function my_create_item( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    // your code here...
}
```

<sub>The actual code that performs the new row/data insertion will depend entirely on you, but you would want to use [`wpdb::insert()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/).</sub>

#### Additional Notes

1. A route's namespace is composed of `<vendor name>/<version>`, and you should use your own vendor name, e.g. `my-plugin`, and not `wp`. So `my-plugin/v2` is good, but `wp/v2` shouldn't be used.

   Because the ["Routes and Endpoints → Namespaces" section](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#namespaces) stated:

   > **Do not place anything into the `wp`  namespace unless you are making endpoints with the intention of merging them into core.**
2. Remember to always set a ***permission** callback* for your endpoints.

   See ["Routes and Endpoints → Permissions Callback"](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#permissions-callback) and ["Adding Custom Endpoints → Permissions Callback](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#permissions-callback)" for more details, but for REST API routes that are intended to be public, one can use [`__return_true()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__return_true/) as the permission callback, i.e. `'permission_callback'`  `=>` `'__return_true'`.
3. You would also want to register your endpoint arguments using the [`args` key](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#arguments), and set a validate and sanitize callback which will validate/sanitize the arguments. E.g.

   - The args for Endpoint 2 above:

     ```php
     // Endpoint 2 - create items.
     array(
         'methods'             => 'POST',
         'callback'            => 'my_create_item',
         'permission_callback' => function () {
             // This is just an example of checking the user's permissions..
             return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
         },
         'args'                => my_create_item_args(),
     )
     ```
   - The `my_create_item_args()` function:

     ```php
     function my_create_item_args() {
         return array(
             'user_from' => array(
                 'required'          => true,
                 'validate_callback' => function ( $param ) {
                     return is_numeric( $param );
                 },
             ),
             'message'   => array(
                 'required'          => true,
                 'sanitize_callback' => function ( $param ) {
                     // this allows basic HTML tags like <strong> and <em>
                     return wp_filter_kses( $param );

                     // this allows line breaks, but strips all HTML tags
     //              return sanitize_textarea_field( $param );
                 },
             ),
             // ... other args.
         );
     }
     ```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have added updated coding that i placed in my functions.php file in the original question. i get the following error. Any thoughts?:{'code': 'rest_no_route', 'message': 'No route was found matching the URL and request method.', 'data': {'status': 404}}

Comment: That's because your POST *endpoint* was not registered, and it's because when supplying two or more endpoints, the 3rd parameter must be an array of endpoints, e.g. `register_rest_route( 'foo/v1', '/bar', array( array( 'methods' => 'GET', ... ), array( 'methods' => 'POST', ... ) ) )` - note the endpoints are nested in an array, but yours were not. And please apply other advices in my answer, e.g. use your own namespace like `my-plugin/v1` and not `wp/v2`, and always set a `permission_callback` (even for a public endpoint).

Comment: OK thanks. I'll give it a go.

Comment: I have edited the code in the original question. All seems to work fine, except when i add  the wpdb::insert into the post_function (its hashed in the above code), i get an error. Is there anything wrong with the wpdb::insert statement? the echo $body code line yields the following response: {"user_from":10,"message":"hello world"}

Comment: Also, is there a method to validate callback that userid entered in user_from actually exists? Or I would have to code it out manually with an if statement. Much appreciated.

Comment: OK i found solutions for all above, ive posted my final answer in original question.